# Determining the type of a differential form on an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves

As we know, there are three types of differential forms on an elliptic curve: those of first kind  -- which have no poles or zeroes, those of the second kind -- which have poles with residue 0, and third kind -- which have simple poles with non-zero residue.

Now, if the elliptic curve is given in Weierstrass form I know that $\frac{dx}{y}$ is a differential of the first kind, and that $\frac{xdx}{y}$ is a differential of the second kind, and one could similarly write a differential of the third kind.

However, I was wondering if there is a way of determining the type of a meromorphic differential form, say $\frac{u(x_1,x_2)dx_1}{f(x_1,x_2)}$, where $f$ is a cubic polynomial in the variables $x_1,x_2$, and $u(x_1,x_2)$ is any polynomial, without changing variables to get $f$ into Weirestrass form?

Comment: The first is a differential on $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$. Is the second is a differential form on a general (affine) cubic curve $f(x_1,x_2)=0$? How are you coming by your analogy of $f$ and $y$, or do you mean to have any polynomial $v(x_1, x_2)$ in the denominator?

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Yes, $f(x_1,x_2)=0$ is a general cubic curve. I am assuming that it's non-singular and it has a point over some field. Sorry, I should've specified. Then I could change coordinates to get it to Weierestrass form $f(x,y)=-y^2+x^3+ax+b$. But do I have to do this to decide what type a given meromorphic differential form is?

Comment: If you're given a $1$-form on any curve, you can always go out and find its zeroes and poles...

Comment: @Mummytheturkey any tips on how to do this in practice?

Comment: It's just a matter of untying the definitions. Standard books on Riemann surfaces should have examples. The section on the invariant differential in Silverman starts off by more or less doing this calculation on $y^2 + a_1xy +... = 0$. Computer algebra like Magma can do it in seconds.

Comment: @baltazar I computed the zeroes and poles of a differential in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3910573), though it's still on a hyperelliptic curve. Given a curve $C: f(x,y) = 0$, differentiating gives $f_x \, dx + f_y \, dy = 0$. Since $C$ is smooth, then at each point $dx$ or $dy$ (or both) will be a generator for the module of differentials. For instance, if $dx$ is a generator at $P$, then near $P$ any differential $\omega$ can be written $\omega = f(x) \, dx$ for some rational function $f$. The order of zero or pole of $\omega$ at $P$ is then the order of zero or pole of $f$.